# How does one print or display output in MIPS WITHOUT syscall

Tags: printing, mips

I am stumped with how to do this. I know how to print it out with syscall, but am clueless on how to do it without syscall.

How would one go about doing this?

Family is Pic32 32 bit

Device is Pic32MX795F512L

Using MPLAB

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MARS or QtSPIM, there is a console to which you can send characters.  It has a keyboard and printer, and it uses memory mapped I/O.  It is pretty easy to use busy wait loops to send characters to the console's printer.

Or one can develop a full-blown interrupt-driven device driver and mini-os for user programs to interact with.  When I do this I use MIPS trap instructions (`teqi` & `tnei`) for the main program to invoke operating system functionality.  The operating system services work as an exception handler in kernel mode, which catches both traps from the main program, and interrupts from devices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am using Pic32MX795F512L programming on MPLAB

Comment: there may be a serial port you can print to, or, some led display.  probably memory mapped, so, figure out how devices connect to this kit.  alternately, you can print to a block of regular memory and maybe bring that memory up in the debugger.